# How to pass data to containerview based on segmented control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I have the following setting, my ViewController has a segmented Control with 4 segments and two containerviews A and B with corresponding ViewControllers.

If the first segment is selected the containerView A is showed and B is hidden. If one of the other three is selected, B is shown and A hidden and the selected index is passed to the destination view controller of B using the `prepareForSegue` method. I want to handle the remaining cases there since only a plot will change in these 3 segments.

I thought I only need one viewcontroller for the 3 latter segments. But if the SegmentedControl changes, the prepare for segue method is not called anymore and I can't handle the different cases in the ViewController of B.. any ideas how to solve this?

I already tried to manually call the segue if the segmented control changed but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method:

```
-[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(segmentTapped:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

The UISegmentedControl object is passed as a target to the selector you choose, and you can then get the selected index off of that, and update your VC's accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! would you min explaining in more detail? I am super new to ios programming and it's all still a bit blurry :)

Comment: Absolutely, I actually just started as an iOS developer about 4 or 5 months ago so I know the feeling! Basically, set this method on the segmentedControl (replace segmentedControl with whatever yours is named) and set the selector to be the method you want called when the switch is toggled (I usually use segmentedTapped: or segmentChanged:). Now, every time you change, this method gets called in the VC where you have the segmentedController. You can then call the selectedIndex property on the segmented controller to figure out which VC should be showing and how, then do all your setup in there

Comment: as you would do in prepareForSegue:. Let me know if that's not clear, I know a lot of it can be hard to understand when you're still new to iOS programming.

Comment: its good to know where you started right :) How can I assign one of the two viewcontrollers to the containerviews? at the moment my "SegmentedControlChanged" function only sets the hidden properties but I can't figure out how to get to the embedded viewController that comes with it...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, is the VC another class inside of the container view? If so, make sure its declared in your .h of your container view, and make sure all the properties you want to access are declared in the .h of your view controller.

Comment: if have two containerviews A and B which both have an "embed" segue to a viewcontroller. both classes are included and properties are declared. basically I have the property `UIView *containerViewA` and `UIView *containerViewB` (which I hide or not) and these containerviews have their embedded VC's, but how can I access these VCs without having the whole segue.destinationViewController?

Comment: You _should_ be able to call containerViewA.viewController, or setup a method -[containerViewA getViewController] that simply returns self.viewController inside of containerViewA or B. Then you should be able to access any properties you can in the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to access the embedded viewcontroller over its containerview (which is an uiview)

Comment: What kinds of properties are you trying to set on the viewController?

Comment: managedobjectcontext (which is the same for every case), an array filled with data for the plot (different based on the integer of the selected index) and the integer of the selected index...

Comment: I was able to solve it using a property *myViewController and storing it as self.myViewController= segue.destinationViewController and then accessing self.myViewController.dataarray and so on in Controlchanged:sender: ... fancy pointer stuff, still figuring it out :)